# How do I efficiently limit query to the presence of an id in a many-to-many relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

**The scenario:**

I am building a search system for a given set of data. Most of this is straight forward - *where record title contains X, where record date before Y*, etc. Where I am running into difficulty is essentially a category search. Each record belongs to zero or more categories (a relationship pivot table exists such that each row contains a record and a category), and when the user searches for Category A, I want to return all of the records that belong to that category. I've gotten this working with a whereHas, but it seems inordinately slow. In this instance, assume $category is a numeric id that is correctly validated as a category, and $records is an eloquent query builder that has not yet been executed by a get, pagination, all, etc (my function checks to see if several $request->input parameters are defined, then attaches a where to $record as required by the specified parameters, only executing it after all parameters have been considered):

```
if(!empty($category)) {
 $records = $records->whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category) 
  {
   $query->where('category_id', $category);
  });
}
```

This **works**, but as there are 7000+ records, 7000+ relationships defined in the pivot, and roughly 30 'categories', the search takes longer than I am comfortable leaving it. My unconfirmed thought is that the where query is executing for every record, thus leading to hundreds or thousands of queries.

I've debated approaching this using the raw query builder and just passing the list of record id's that have that category and using a simple where to filter the record collection before it's executed, but it seems counter-intuitive, leading me to believe there must be a better way.

**The Question**
How do I efficiently limit the records returned by $records->get() to those records with a defined relationship to category $category.

**Edit 2018-01-16**

To clarify, while I could simply do $category->records to return all records belonging to a category, this is part of a larger search engine. The full structure of the code looks like this:

```
If($subject_search_term) {
   $records->where('subject', $subject_search_term)
}

If(some other search criteria is defined) {
   $records->where(someothercriteria);
}

If(Category search criteria is defined) {
   $records->whereHas(something);
}

$records->paginate(20);
```

Furthermore, there are two of these many-to-many relationships that I need to query (in addition to 'categories', lets say there is also a 'subject' that is independent of it, but similar structure and idea). As far as I know, I need to build the query off records and filter it accordingly.

**EDIT 2**

For anyone else with this problem, it seems the vastly more efficient way (and the most efficient that I've found) is Joel Hinz's comment - use the DB facade to build a raw query, pluck the id's from it, and use that in a whereIn clause.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean... can't you just do `$category->records` if you want the records for a category?

Comment: That would work if that was all I wanted, yes.

Unfortunately, the code is written in such a way that this is all building one large query, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Ah, sorry, now I understand. You could run a query on the pivot table to get all record ids of that category and then do a `$records->whereIn('id', $allOfThoseRecordIds)` for instance.

Comment: True, I had thought of that, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: For fast and efficient searches you should consider either creating a denormalized table for search or use a search service like elasticsearch backed by [scout](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scout). Raw queries might help but there's only so much you can optimize via queries before you reach unoptimizable lower bounds

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- **[mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery: Convert has() and whereHas() constraints to non-dependent subqueries.](https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-non-dependent-subquery)**
- [mpyw/eloquent-has-by-join: Convert has() and whereHas() constraints to join() ones for single-result relations.](https://github.com/mpyw/eloquent-has-by-join)

```php
if(!empty($category)) {
 $records = $records->hasByNonDependentSubquery('categories', function($query) use ($category) 
  {
   $query->where('category_id', $category);
  });
}
```

That's all. Happy Eloquent Life!